# After adding a scope to a OpenID Connect Identity Provider (an Azure AD tenant), the new scope is not returned in the idp_access_token

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

**Environment**

Node.js/Express Web Application on Azure

**Desired Behaviour**

After a single sign on login, the `scp` value within the `idp_access_token` should include a newly added scope, i.e:  `Sites.ReadWrite.All`.

**Actual Behaviour**

The `scp` value does not include the newly added scope.

**Steps to Reproduce**

`Azure AD` > `[ switch directory to Azure AD B2C ]` > `Azure AD B2C` > `Identity Providers`

Click on the existing entry for `Open ID Connect`.

(This provider enables users from the 'home' Azure AD tenant to login using single sign on).

Change the value of the `Scope` field FROM:

```
openid profile User.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All
```

TO:

```
openid profile User.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All Sites.ReadWrite.All
```

In other words, I just added the `Sites.ReadWrite.All` scope.

Perform a single sign on login.

Inspect the `idp_access_token` value that is returned at jwt.ms.

The `scp` property is missing the newly added scope (`Sites.ReadWrite.All`):

```
Directory.ReadWrite.All openid profile Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All User.ReadWrite.All email
```

I have tried logging out and logging in again and I still only get the 'old' scope value.

In other words, the new scope has not been added to the `idp_access_token`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it was just a matter of waiting, but after:

- writing the original question
- logging out of app in local development environment
- re-starting app in local development environment
- attempting login again in local development environment

I was presented with an updated consent screen:

[image]

After Accepting that, the new scopes were returned in the `idp_access_token`.